# in search of: DanF

Tags: discussion, users

As I mentioned ([here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54501873#54501873) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54532609#54532609)), [the user DanF](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5275/danf) has not been online for a while. While I do not know this user at all personally, I feel there is some room for concern.

For as long as I have been on this site, I recall that DanF is always an active participant. Not only does he not go long without logging on, but he also frequently asks many, many questions.

I have had many great interactions with this user, personally. Furthermore, through these interactions, it was evident that DanF is an older (not *old* old) individual.
Based on the date he was last online here (March 25 , 2020), and the historical significance of that date (Coronavirus GLOBAL outbreak), I am concerned for the well-being of this user. If you are connected to this user, please consider reaching out, and updating us here in the bleachers.

If you have noticed similar such anomalies, please consider editing this post.

-A concerned user

Answer (score 29, accepted):

DanF gave me his email address some years ago when ordering copies of "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?". For what it's worth, I was not a moderator then, so my having this information was not related to an exercise of mod powers.

I emailed him to say that the community is concerned and ask if he's OK. Thank God, he responded that he's perfectly fine, just less able to participate online these days. He said that our concern is "extremely touching, meaningful, and comforting."

As proof that I have indeed exchanged correspondence with the actual DanF, I offer the following passage from his email:

> The most poignant part for me was being away from shul, esp. since I'm a Ba'al Kri'ah. We reopened last week, and I can tell you that last week and into the foreseeable future, Shabbat is going to cost me a ton of money as I have to donate for taking all 7 aliyot each week. At the end, the shul won't just be getting a Kiddush. It will get a shmorg, buffet and Viennese Table plus fancy cakes to go, at this rate.

May we all merit to share in such kiddushes together, in good health.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that he's doing all right. Thank you for the update!

Comment: That passage is indeed incontrovertible evidence that you corresponded with the actual DanF.